# Spring boot - binding properties [Configuration properties]

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I work on spring boot version: `2.0.2.RELEASE`. In my `application.yml` I have:

```
cars:
  color-to-brands:
    red: car1, car2
    blue: car3, car4
```

and my config class looks like this:

```
@Getter @Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cars")
public class CarsProperties {

    private Map<String, List<String>> colorToBrands = Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

When I start the app, I'm keep getting:

> Failed to bind properties under 'cars.color-to-brands' to
>   java.util.Map>:
>
> ```
> Reason: Failed to bind properties under 'cars.color-to-brands' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.String>>
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Update your application's configuration

Now, to summarize what I have already done to fix it:

1. [According to documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) I **have added a dependency** that gives
   me annotation processor for my `@ConfigurationProperties`:

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
>   <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
>   <optional>true</optional>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. I have **annotation processor enabled**. I'm using Intellij. `Annotation processors` -> `Maven default annotation processors profile` has ticked `Enable annotation processing`, `Processor path:` contains `(...)\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-configuration-processor\2.0.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar`, `Store generated sources relative to: Module content root`,
3. In the pom file I've **added path for this processor** (among others I
   use):

> ```
> <plugin>
> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
> <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
> <version>3.8.0</version>
> <configuration>
>   <source>1.8</source>
>   <target>1.8</target>
>   <annotationProcessorPaths>
>       <path>
>           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
>           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
>           <version>${lombok.version}</version>
>       </path>
>       <path>
>           <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
>           <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
>           <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
>       </path>
>       <path>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
>       </path>
>   </annotationProcessorPaths>
>   <compilerArgs>
>       <compilerArg>
>           -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
>       </compilerArg>
>   </compilerArgs>
> </configuration>
> ```

4. In addition, intellij keep showing me a popup inside the `CarsProperties`:

> Re-run Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor to update
>   generated metadata

5. I've skipped `@EnableConfigurationProperties` as:

> [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) says, every project automatically includes
>   @EnableConfigurationProperties.

6. Somewhere in between I also did: `Reimport All Maven Projects`, `clean install`, `Rebuild project`, and `Invalid Caches and Restart`

I'm sitting in front of that computer for few hours now, Can't get it done. What am I doing wrong ? Why it doesn't want to work ?

Answer (score 3):

Updated spring boot version to `2.1.6.RELEASE` and it's fixed